# Starting PuTTY session in a specific directory

Tags: ssh, putty

I use PuTTY to connect to a remote server. I want my SSH session to start on a folder that I specify on the server, so I won't have to do `cd /my/path/` every time I log in. Possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you only want the behavior when you log in through PuTTY, you can use "remote command" in the PuTTY configuration dialog (under Connection/SSH). You would type

```
cd /my/path ; /bin/myshell
```

into the "remote command" field. If you have more complicated stuff to set up, you would type in the name of a script /home/yourname/yourscript for "remote command" which contains something like

```
cd /my/path
all-other-stuff-I-need-to-do
/bin/myshell
```

You need to start the shell manually in your script, otherwise the SSH session will terminate right after your script finishes.

"remote command" has the advantage that you can create different saves sessions in PuTTY where different scripts are called (if you need that).

Of course, if you *always* want to have the same directory (independent of PuTTY) when you log into your account, you can add the `cd` command to  `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` as explained by grawity.

Comment: "remote command" close the shell automatically after logging in

Comment: @RafaSashi yes, that’s why you need to launch the interactive shell which you want to use explicitly at the end of your script...

Comment: yes, the alternative with ~/.profile worked fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

You can add the command to `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`) to be automatically ran on every login.