# Auto start PuTTY from command-line with a specific startup path

Tags: batch, putty, autostart

I start multiple PuTTY sessions everyday with a specific path in each session.

I have made a command in batch file as

```
Start "c:\putty.exe" abc@1.1.1.1 -pw abc123 22
```

How do I proceed further to open PuTTY directly in a specific remote directory.

I have 20 sessions.

Please assist.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a file with two commands, the directory change and the shell start, like:

```
cd /path
/bin/bash
```

Then use the command-line parameter `-m` to "execute" the commands. You will also want to use the `-t` for force TTY back as the `-m` disables it.

```
putty.exe username@example.com -pw password -t -m commands.txt
```

To avoid a separate command file for each sessions, just generate it from the batch file:

```
set SCRIPT_FILE=%TEMP%\commands.txt
echo cd /path > %SCRIPT_FILE%
echo /bin/bash > %SCRIPT_FILE%
putty.exe username@example.com -pw password -t -m %SCRIPT_FILE%
```

References:

- [PuTTY command-line](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)
- [Starting PuTTY session in a specific directory](https://superuser.com/q/290258/213663)
- [PuTTY: Run a remote command after login & keep the shell running](https://superuser.com/q/587629/213663)

---

If you want GUI for managing sessions with specific initial remote path, you can use WinSCP.

- [WinSCP can work as session manager for PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_winscp_as_putty_session_manager)
- and it can be [configured to open PuTTY in a specific path](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#putty_startup_directory).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*