# How can I start bash in specific directory when connecting to Windows via SSH with PuTTY

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

Basically the same as this question,
[Starting PuTTY session in a specific directory](https://superuser.com/questions/290258/starting-putty-session-in-a-specific-directory), but for Windows.

I want to ssh into a Windows machine, change directory, then start `bash`. In remote command under *Connection > SSH*, I tried `cd c:\myproject & bash` but it doesn't work. It just opens `bash` shell under `~` directory.

I want to use the GUI and not command line because I have different profiles I want to save that open into different directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was enclose the entire command in quotes as Martin suggests.

```
"cd c:\myproject & bash"
```